# Custom Viewcontroller transition bug on rotation of the device

Tags: ios, model-view-controller, custom-transition

I am trying to customise the navigation controller push and pop transition.
It's basically alpha animation is happening. 
Here is the code.
It's working really cool until i rotate the iPad after presentation and when I dismiss the presenting viewController the containView stays there. 
I mean the  [transitionContext containerView]  never rotates with the device and becomes visible after the dismissing the presenting viewcontroller.

```
- (void)animateTransition:(id<UIViewControllerContextTransitioning>)transitionContext {

    self.transitionContext = transitionContext;
    if(self.isReverse) {
        [self hide:transitionContext];
    } else {
        [self show:transitionContext];
    }
}

#pragma mark - Helper Method
- (void)show:(id<UIViewControllerContextTransitioning>)transitionContext {

    UIViewController *toViewController = [transitionContext viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextToViewControllerKey];
    UIViewController *fromViewController = [transitionContext viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextFromViewControllerKey];;

    toViewController.view.frame = fromViewController.view.frame;
    [[transitionContext containerView] addSubview:toViewController.view];
    [transitionContext containerView].backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    toViewController.view.alpha = 0.0;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:[self transitionDuration:transitionContext]
                          delay:0.0
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve | UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                     animations:^{
                         toViewController.view.alpha = 1.0;
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                         [transitionContext completeTransition:![transitionContext transitionWasCancelled]];
                     }];
}

- (void)hide:(id<UIViewControllerContextTransitioning>)transitionContext {

    UIViewController *toViewController   = [transitionContext viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextToViewControllerKey];
    UIViewController *fromViewController = [transitionContext viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextFromViewControllerKey];

    [[transitionContext containerView] insertSubview:toViewController.view belowSubview:fromViewController.view];

    fromViewController.view.alpha = 1.0;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:[self transitionDuration:transitionContext]
                          delay:0.0
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve | UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                     animations:^{
                         fromViewController.view.alpha = 0.0;
                     } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                         [transitionContext completeTransition:![transitionContext transitionWasCancelled]];
                     }];
}
```

Comment: Can you post any screenshots of the issue, once you have rotated the device? If the device is not rotated the transition works correctly?

Comment: Yeah! it's works correctly if device is not rotated.

Comment: Please post a screenshot of what your actual resulting screen looks like

Comment: Post your project somewhere